# How do I set the default value of a dropdown to that of a related dropdown

Tags: cakephp

please could someone help with the following:

I have 3 related tables

Users (id, name, network_id, application_id)
Networks (id, name, application_id)
Applications (id, name)

A network will have a default application selected (from the list of applications with app_id and name as fields). A user can select the network as well as an application they wish to use (from list of applications).

I have created the models, controllers and views and and all the dropdowns appear fine and allow me to select a value BUT how would I set the default value of the Users>application dropdown to that of the corresponding Networks>application_id?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Server-side, i.e. in Cake try adding the selected parameter, viz:

```
echo $form->select(string $fieldName, array $options, mixed $selected, array $attributes, boolean $showEmpty)
```

Where `$selected` is the *value* of the default option.

Client-side, you'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use select(), or text(), or radio() etc. it's terrible practice. You should use input()

```
echo $form->input('', array('type'=>'select', 'label'=>'', 'options'=>$discipline, 'default'=>8));
```

Where type present the select box, option requires array for list of dropdown and default value would be of index 8

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $form->input('', array('type'=>'select', 'label'=>'', 'options'=>$option_list, 'value'=>7));
```

Here 7 is your key value in $option_list.

Try it...

Answer (score 0):

I have fetched value in variable `$equipData['unit']`. The code below works for me:

```
echo $this->Form->input('unit_id',array('label' => false,'selected'=>$equipData['unit'],'options'=> $op_arr));
```